# Inserting Text Next to SVG element

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have this code that displays a red dot next to some text, BUT, I want the red dot in front of the text, not after it. Seems like this should be simple but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script>
function addRow() {

            var firstRow = document.getElementById('rowOne');
            var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
            var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
        
            firstRow.innerHTML = "Live Now";
            firstRow.className = "mytext";
            firstRow.style = "color: rgb(230, 0, 0)";
        
            svg.setAttribute("height",40);
            svg.setAttribute("width",51);
            svg.setAttribute("style",'vertical-align:middle');
            firstRow.append(svg);

        
            circle.setAttribute("cx", 20);
            circle.setAttribute("cy", 20);
            circle.setAttribute("r", 9);
            circle.setAttribute("style", 'fill: rgb(230, 0, 0)');
        
            svg.appendChild(circle);
        
        

        }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="addRow()">
<table id="myTable" width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="myshadow">
  <tbody>
  
<tr id = "rowOne" onclick="DoNav('https://www.praisechapelparamount.com/livestream')" style="cursor: pointer"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your html is not valid. Your _Live Now_ text is inside a table row `<tr>` with no `<td>` or `<th>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to change append to prepend, on firstRow.append.

append put the element on the final, prepend on the start

```
firstRow.prepend(svg);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try using jQuery method prepend
First add a script element in head tag :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can try $(svg).prepend(circle)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create HTML or SVG the 'complex' `createElement` way.

```html
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <style>
    body {
      --fontsize: 5em;
    }
    
    .mytext {
      font-size: var(--fontsize);
    }
    
    svg {
      background: lightgreen;
      width: 1em;
      height: 1em;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    let circle = `<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>` +
      `<circle cx='35%' cy='65%' r='35%' fill='currentColor'/></svg>`;

    function addRow() {
      let firstRow = document.getElementById('rowOne');
      firstRow.innerHTML = circle + "Live Now";
      firstRow.classList.add("mytext");
      firstRow.style.color = "rgb(230, 0, 0)";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="addRow()">
  <table id="myTable" width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="myshadow">
    <tbody>
      <tr id="rowOne" onclick="DoNav('https://www.praisechapelparamount.com/livestream')" style="cursor: pointer"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! Although the first answer was sufficient, I like this simplified version better.